# Angular mono-repo library making using ng-packagr

Tags: angular, build, monorepo, ng-packagr

I have the below **mono repo** folder structure for my **Angular** application.

[image: directory/ | ---apps/ | | | ---app1/ | | | ---app2/ | ---libs/ | ---library1/ | | | | | ---src/ | | | ---library2/ | | | | | ---src/ | | ---angular.json | ---package.json | ---README.md | ---tsconfig.json]

I am using library1 and library2 in app1/app2, also publishing both the libraries as .tgz separately to be consumed by other angular applications.

**I am using ng-packagr to Compile and package Angular libraries in Angular Package Format (APF).**

to create library using below commands :

```
   **ng build --library1**

   **npm pack**
```

In directory/angular.json

```
"projects": {
     "library1": {
        "root": "libs/library1",
        "sourceRoot": "libs/library1/src",
        "projectType": "library",
        "prefix": "library1",
        "architect": {
            "build": {
                "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
                "options": {
                    "tsConfig": "libs/library1/tsconfig.lib.json",
                    "project": "libs/library1/ng-package.json"
                },
                "configurations": {
                    "production": {
                        "project": "libs/library1/ng-package.prod.json"
                    }
                }
            }
            }
```

In directory/libs/library1/ng-package.json

```
{
"$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
"dest": "../../dist/libs/library1",
"lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/index.ts"
}
}
```

What I Need :

1. Now I want to combine library1 and library 2  to create a single library  may be libraryAll(libraryAll.tgz) which will export libray1 and library 2.
2. Also I need  a shared module  which will be consumed by both libraries and will be a part of final library package.

Comment: You can create [GitSubmodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) feature, in this way you will be able to create new separate repo which has the common features and can include it wherever necessary

Comment: yes that I can do but it will again require different publish of individual libraries

Answer (score 1):

To combine two libraries into one i suggest you to create a third one that imports the first two and expose it with a different index.ts .
This if you want to maintains it separately in all means.

Both the first and second library needs to be compiled before are used and exposed by the third one.

Ex. LibraryAllModule that exports Library1Module and Library2Module.

The index.ts will looks like:

```
export { LibraryAllModule } from './libs/libraryAll/library-all.module';
export { Library1Module } from './libs/library1/library1.module';
export { Library2Module } from './libs/library2/library2.module';
```

Or an other approach it could be to report the code from both libraries into a new library divided by modules.

The index.ts will looks like this:

```
export { LibraryAllModule } from './libs/libraryAll/library-all.module';
export { Library1Module } from './libs/libraryAll/library1/library1.module';
export { Library2Module } from './libs/libraryAll/library2/library2.module';
```

By combining the 2 libraries into a common library it will be also easier for you to crate a common module to share between both. You can declare it in the folder 'libraryAll' and import it in both libraries then.

Answer (score 0):

I think that firstly you need to create multi-project structure that angular provides. You can generate libs and apps via the `ng generate lib` or `ng generate application` command.

Then for your libs you can package. Check this for more info: https://izifortune.com/multiple-packages-repository-with-angular/

Comment: I am already using library and following mono repo approach but that is not my question. Please check my question again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your suggestions.

I solved the issue using **ng packagr** ***secondary entry points feature***.

Inside **library 1** I used  existing **library 2** and created another shared-library   **library 3**.

With that I now can  publish package for libraryAll  in including libray 1, libray 2 and libray 3.

I  am also able to publish individual libraries  as well.

[ng packagr secondary point](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/HEAD/docs/secondary-entrypoints.md)

The only major blocker I faced is the import path for library (library-3) in library 1 and library 2 was throwing build error, I was getting rootDir issue as the path was outside the entry point folder. The solution for that I implemented was I imported it from node modules and published the final library.

The below link will explain secondary entry point structure.

The current structure is

[image]

Comment: How do you put into the node_modules and then after you publish how does it installed, if you haven't published it before? Can you share a github project as a demo?